# Creating Wicket Project Using Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, wicket

I try to create a wicket project with:

```
mvn archetype:create 
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart 
-DarchetypeVersion=1.5-M2.1 
-DgroupId=com.mycompany 
-DartifactId=myproject
```

The statement was created with the tool on http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html

If i execute it I get:

```
The META-INF/maven/archetype.xml descriptor cannot be found
```

whats wrong. I am a Maven novice

Every help appreciated

Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** It seems that the Wicket archetype is using the "new" archetype descriptor (i.e. post Archetype 1.0.x). So use the `generate` goal instead of `create`:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket \
      -DarchetypeVersion=1.5-M2.1 \
      -DgroupId=com.mycompany \
      -DartifactId=myproject \
      -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
      -DinteractiveMode=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

---

There seems to be a problem with the archetype.xml of the version 1.5-M2.1 (and the current SNAPSHOT version) of the wicket-archetype-quickstart. I suggest using the previous version and upgrading the version of the wicket artifacts in the generated project:

```
mvn archetype:create \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.4.11 \
-DgroupId=com.mycompany \
-DartifactId=myproject
```

Comment: Sounds right. The archetypes hardly ever change, except for the artifact versions. (+1)

Comment: @seanizer Actually, I just realized they are now using the "new" Archetype descriptor (and was updating my answer). Using `archetype:generate` does work. They should update the logic of the UI generating the command :S